Cyclic homology with coefficients in a bimodule
I've recently been trying to understand Hochschild and cyclic co/homology better, and I've noticed that while it's common to define the Hochschild homology $\mathrm{HH}_{\bullet}(A;M)$ of an $R$-algebra $A$ with coefficients in an $A$-bimodule $M$, the same doesn't seem to apply to cyclic homology, which is instead only defined for $R$-algebras, without a variant with coefficients in a bimodule.
Trying to understand this, I've found the following articles:

Kaledin, Cyclic homology with coefficients, published as part of the book Algebra, Arithmetic, and Geometry
, and also available as arXiv:0702068.
Donadze–Ladra, On the non-existence of a cyclic homology theory with coefficients.

The first article above constructs a category whose objects are bimodules with extra structure, which serve as coefficients for cyclic co/homology.
The second article proves it's impossible to extend cyclic homology to have coefficients in bimodules while also having it be related to Hochschild homology via the Connes periodicity sequence.
On the other hand, I've also heard about the following two approaches for extending cyclic homology to have coefficients in a bimodule:

Let $M$ be an $R$-bimodule and consider the cyclic operator $t_n$ on $M\otimes_RA^{n}$ given by
$$t_n(m\otimes_{R}a_1\otimes_R\cdots\otimes_Ra_n)\mathbin{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}(-1)^na_nm\otimes_R a_1\otimes_R\cdots\otimes_R a_{n-1}.$$
Consider the bimodule of noncommutative differentials $\Omega^{n}(A)$ and define a cyclic operator $t_n\colon M\otimes_R\Omega^{n}(A)\to M\otimes_R\Omega^{n}(A)$ by
$$t_n(m\otimes_{R}a_0\mathrm{d}a_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}a_n)\mathbin{\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}}(-1)^nma_n\otimes_R\mathrm{d}a_0\wedge\cdots\wedge\mathrm{d}a_{n-1}.$$

We (supposedly) could then build a bicomplex using these, and define cyclic homology with coefficients in $M$ by considering the totalization of these complexes.
Question I. Do these two approaches really work and lead to anything useful? I have reasons to be skeptical of them, but I'm not familiar enough with the field to be sure.
Question II. More generally, what is known about trying to extend cyclic homology to have coefficients in bimodules? I've found the two papers above which describe some aspects of the problem a bit, but think an expert would likely be able to shine some light on the general situation.

The operator defined in 1 does not appear to preserve degree: the inputs are tensors of length n+1 and the outputs are tensors of length n

I must admit (as someone who came to Hochschild and cyclic cohomology from the point of view of algebras, rather than category theory) that I don't understand why one wants to have "cyclic (co)homology with coefficients". It is an invariant of an associative algebra; why does one want to bring modules in?

@YemonChoi I don't know what motivation Emily has in mind, but here is one motivation for cyclic homology with coeffs. that I think is relatively natural. To calculate Hochschild homology of an algebra $A$, you can filter the coefficient bimodule $A$ so that the associated graded has a much simpler action, then run the resulting spectral sequence to calculate the former by starting with the latter. Geller-Reid-Weibel's calculation of algebraic K-theory of plane singularities used this method. Can you do it with cyclic homology, not just Hochschild? You would need cyclic $H_*$ w/ coeffs!

@user509184 Thanks - although this is where I would reach for the Connes-Tsygan exact sequence to be honest (but then I am used to working in characteristic zero)

@YemonChoi I think my motivation here likely won't help, as it's quite disconnected from algebra and comes from category theory. There you can associate to any functor $D\colon\mathcal{C}^{\mathsf{op}}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathsf{Sets}$ (which plays the role of our bimodule there) a "Hochschild co/simplicial set", and the $\pi_0$ of this co/simplicial set recovers the co/end of $D$. I recently realised one can repeat this construction and build a co/cyclic set, which would lead to a notion of "co/cyclic co/ends", so I'd like to understand the situation for algebra better.

From a topological point of view, Hochschild homology of a bimodule is capturing cohomology of homotopy fixed points of a map. If the map is the identity, this gives the loop space, which has a circle action, hence cyclic homology: S^1 equivariant cohomology of this loop space. More generally, HH of a bimodule is the invariant of a TFT on a circle with a marking, while if the bimodule is diagonal this is the value on S^1, hence has rotation symmetry. From this POV, there's no reason to expect a circle action on HH with other coefficients, so a cyclic theory with bimodule coefficients.
